# Indexing Webpage on google but cant find it on the search bar with site:domain.com

Tags: indexing, sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console

first time indexing a webpage on Google so I barely know anything about this.
I did an url inspection and it returns correctly, after that I requested an indexation and even added a sitemap which state is correct.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNuWf.png)

But when I search on google "site:domain.com" it returns 0 results, but if I search on the search bar [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) it does find it. I read on the documentation that indexing might take some days, is this why searching for "site:domain.com" on the search bar returns 0 results? Because it hasn't been indexed yet? If not, why is it not showing with this search?

Thank you for any help :)

Edit
If anyone has the same question, yes, it takes some time to appear, in my case just took less than 24h, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it takes some time to appear, in my case just took less than 24h